# Install from Persistent LiveUSB, including files / changes on casper-rw

Tags: installation, live-usb, ubiquity, persistence

I made a persistent LiveUSB drive that I've used for a while now, and I would like to install that LiveUSB environment to the harddrive of a computer.

I've tried simply installing it using the default method (Ubiquity), but it did not install any of the programs / files / settings that are stored on my casper-rw partition.  Is there an easy way to install the full persistent environment from a LiveUSB drive onto a harddisk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Boot from your thumb drive.

Partition your drive so it looks like this or modify the directions accordingly:

```
sda1=swap
sda2=/
```

Then do all this as root:

```
  
~#mkswap /dev/sda1
~#swapon /dev/sda1

~#echo 'This one is probably un-necessary'
~#mkdir /mnt/

~#mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/migrate/
~#cp --preserve -R /{bin,dev,home,root,usr,etc,lib,opt,sbin,var,boot} /mnt/migrate/ 
~#mkdir /mnt/migrate/{mnt,proc,sys,tmp}
~#mount --bind /dev/ /mnt/migrate/dev/
~#mount -t proc proc /mnt/migrate/proc/

~#chroot /mnt/migrate/ /bin/bash
~#update-grub
~#grub-install /dev/sdX
~#reboot
```

Minimal modification from some old directions for installing BT3 [here](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=11333#post73975).

Also, you'll need to fix your /etc/fstab

Not the Ubuntu-ish way to do this, but it works.

@OP Nice work on the USRP by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I was hoping there was some hidden configuration option in Ubiquity, but scripting up a chroot isn't too awful, all things considered =)

Also, thanks for the USRP nod ;)